# Extracting XML nodes in Python

Tags: python, xml

This is part of an XML document that I have:

```
<tr><td>Image:</td><td>
<a href="http://live.astrometry.net/status.php?job=alpha-201104-6758393&amp;get=fullsize.png">fullsize.png</a></td></tr>
```

I need to extract the href attribute "of the `<a>` element after the `<td>` element with content 'Image:'". The `<a>` element has no other id or class attributes that I can use.

Sorry if that sounds complicated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need help with the syntax of a specific parser, or are you trying to find an XML parser for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the final elegant (I hope ;) answer with a single XPath expression

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(your_text)
print root.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Image')]/following-sibling::td/a/@href")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input file is just like your excerpt, the following code may help you:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

def tdlinks(xml):
    o = []
    l = parseString(xml).getElementsByTagName('td')
    while l != []:
        if l[0].firstChild.wholeText == unicode('Image:') and len(l) > 1:
            if l[1].getElementsByTagName('a') != []:
                o.append(l[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href'))
                l.pop(1)
        l.pop(0)
    return o
```

Take a look at the minidom documentation. It may help you to improve the code if you find any anomaly during its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use lxml http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Your [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) would look like `/tr/td[1]/a` to get the element, then you can do `el.attrib['href']`

You can actually traverse the tree without XPath, but it's very powerful and useful tool

Comment: Based on his question, he would need to query the td after the td containing "Image:".  I think there is a "next sibling" selector for Xpath, right?

Comment: yes, for sure (though I don't remember it :). may be if this is so complicated (the're multiple td's, only 1 contains 'Image:' text) the solution would be 1. select ALL td's, iterate, check their `text().startswith('Image'), then select its next sibling`

Comment: the selector is `following-sibling` (http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parseString("""<tr><td>Image:</td><td>
<a href="http://live.astrometry.net/status.php?job=alpha-201104-6758393&amp;get=fullsize.png">fullsize.png</a></td></tr>
""")

print dom.toxml() + "\n"

links = (a.attributes['href'].value for a in dom.getElementsByTagName('a') 
    if a.parentNode.nodeName == 'td' and a.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild.data == 'Image:')

for link in links:
    print link
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><tr><td>Image:</td><td>
<a href="http://live.astrometry.net/status.php?job=alpha-201104-6758393&amp;get=fullsize.png">fullsize.png</a></td></tr>

http://live.astrometry.net/status.php?job=alpha-201104-6758393&get=fullsize.png
```